# Simple BackboneJS API call

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm try to retrieve JSON data from an API using BackboneJS, but I can not figure out why my code is not working.

```
var foodUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';

var foods = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: foodUrl
});

var foodTypes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: foods
});

var Food = new foodTypes();

var bar = new foods({
    url: foodUrl
});

Food.add(bar);

console.log(Food.get(bar));
```

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#), it's short and well explained. Then, if it's not enough, search in google for a Backbone tutorial. You'll get started quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest call to an API with Backbone:

```
var model = new Backbone.Model({ id: 1 });
model.fetch({ url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' });
// GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
```

A more complete example would include extending a [Backbone Model](http://backbonejs.org/#Model) to specify the default [`urlRoot`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot). A Backbone Model should be used to contain only one object of a data model, while a collection is an array of objects.

```
// create a model class
var Food = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/',
});

// create an instance of that model class
var model = new Food({ id: 1 });

// make the async API request
model.fetch();
// GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
```

A model fetch expect to receive a JSON attributes hash by default.

A fetch request is async, so you won't be able to use the attributes right away, you'll need to use a callback for that.

```
model.fetch({
    success: function(){
        console.log(model.attributes);
    }
});
```

You could also fetch an array of objects using a collection.

```
var FoodCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Food,
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'
});

var collection = new FoodCollection();

collection.fetch({
    success: function(){
        console.log(collection.models);
    }
});
```

Comment: I only hope that OP notices you used Capital letter for constructor and small for instances... It's very confusing when people reverse the convensions